# Bend Slick Slider

Tags: html, css, reactjs, slick.js

Bend slick slider

I'm currently interested in making a curved/slick slider like the first image. I would like to know how to use CSS effectively to achieve the desired curved shape. I have tried using border-radius and rotate, but haven't been successful so far.

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using SCSS for some variables, you can achieve this effect with the following code:

```
    $pi: 3.14159265358979;
    $cylinder-width: 100vw;
    $face-count: 50;
    $face-deg: (360deg / $face-count);
    $face-width: ($cylinder-width / $face-count);
    $face-shift: ($cylinder-width / $pi / 2);
    
    .face {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #da0060;
      opacity: 0.7;
      height: 100%;
      width: $face-width;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: rotateY(calc(#{$face-deg} * var(--index))) translateZ(
          calc(#{$face-shift} - -6px)
        );
    }
.cylinder {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vw;
  width: $cylinder-width;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

This will create a cylinder with curved faces and focus the transform code of faces, which is doing the primary bending.